# ODE solving mistake in homogeneous and particular solution method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

When I was solving the ODE $x^{'}+2x=e^t$, $x(0)=5$, if using convolution method I got below derivation:

$x=x(0)e^{-2t}+\int_0^t {e^{-2(t-\tau)} e^{\tau} d\tau}=5e^{-2t} +\frac{1}{3}e^t-\frac{1}{3} \\$

Above seems to be correct since I.C. is satistifed. But when I practice the method of homogeneous with particular solution, I came up with wrong solution:

$x_h(t)=x(0)e^{-2t}=5e^{-2t}\\$

$x_p(t)=\frac{1}{3}e^t\\$

$x(t)=x_h(t)+x_p(t))=5e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{3}e^t\\$

The particular solution $x_p(t)$ was by assuming $x_p(t)=Le^{t}$, and plug it into DE so that:

$x_p^{'}(t)+2x_p(t)=e^t\\$

$Le^t+2Le^t=e^t\\$

$L=\frac{1}{3}\\$

$x_p(t)=\frac{1}{3}e^t$

Hopefully my mistake can be pointed out.

Comment: My apology! This should be first order. Already modified the mistake in Eqn.

Answer (score 1):

Both your approaches are slightly wrong.

In the first you have to apply the factor $e^{-2t}$ to the full result of the integration, thus $e^{-2t}\frac{e^{3t}-1}3=\frac13(e^t-e^{-2t})$.

In the second approach you do not evaluate the initial condition on the homogeneous solution. The constant is left as unknown. Only at the end in the general inhomogeneous solution is the constant determined from the initial condition.

Comment: This first approach of convolution also seems wired to me. It says the solution of ODE can be seen as the decaying of initial condition plus the forcing term convoluted with the exponential kernel. But I did not get where is wrong about the homogeneous solution. $x_h$ is the solution satisfying $x_{'}+2x=0$. The $\lambda=-2$, and the coefficient in front of exponential is 5 which is determined from initial condition. So $x_h(t)=5e^{-2t}$

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the formula you used, $x(t)=x(0)\phi(t)+(\phi*(ur))(t)$ where $\phi(t)=e^{-2t}$ is the exponential decay, $u(t)$ the unit ramp function to switch on the forcing at time $t=0$ and $r(t)=e^t$ the forcing function. Then the convolution integral $\int_0^\infty \phi(t-s)u(s)r(s)ds$ gives exactly the integral in the formula.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out I mixed up homogeneous solution and the so-called initial condition response in the convolution method.

Answer (score 1):

$$x'+2x=e^{t}$$
Is a linear ODE whose integrating factor is $I=e^{2t}$, then
$$x(t)=e^{-2t} \int e^{2t} e^{t} dt+C e^{-2t}$$
$$ \implies x(t)=\frac{e^{t}}{3}+C e^{-2t}.$$
$x(0)=5$ gives $C=14/3$. Finally
$$x(t)=\frac{e^{t}}{3}+\frac{14}{3} e^{-2t}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There was right answer in the early reply. Here I pointed my mistake in two processes in the first place:

(1) need to factor $e^{-2t}$ in the integration
$x=x(0)e^{-2t}+\int_0^t {e^{-2(t-\tau)} e^{\tau} d\tau}=5e^{-2t}+e^{-2t}\int_0^te^{3\tau}d\tau=\frac{14}{3}e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{3}e^t $

(2) initial condition applies to final solution, instead of homogeneous solution

$x_h(t)=\alpha e^{-2t}$ where $\alpha$ is unknow yet
$x_p(t)=\frac{1}{3}e^t$
$x(t)=x_h(t)+x_p(t))=\alpha e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{3}e^t$, apply $x(0)=5$ to get
$\alpha=\frac{14}{3}$,
$\Rightarrow x(t)=\frac{14}{3}e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{3}e^t$